# Макрос в LibreOffice Writer. Конвертация в заглавные буквы

Tags: макросы, libre-office

Как в словах с двумя буквами «а» и более сделать все буквы заглавными с помощью макросов в *LibreOffice Writer* ?

Comment: Смысл? Задание из контрольной?

Comment: Да, просто так я бы не стала это делать)